# wxWidgets and loop-based applications

Tags: wxwidgets

My wxWidgets app (a game editor) interfaces with a game lib that should be used in a loop-based approach. The game lib has a method, mainLoop(), to be called N times per second. The game editor UI allow the users to do things that can change the state of the game lib. I want to avoid that this happens when the mainLoop() is called. Users should be able to change the state of the game lib (adding-removing things and so on) only when the mainLoop() method is 'running'.

How can i do this? The game editor is written for Windows platforms. I have seen a class called wxEventLoopBase, but i have not found anything useful about it (code examples).

Comment: Did you really mean change the state of the lib when the loop is running? Or when it's *not* running, which would seem to make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [wxTimer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_timer.html) where you can specify a timer callback every so many milliseconds or look at implementing an [OnIdle](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_idle_event.html) method where you can call the mainloop when there are not any GUI events to process.